# Windows 10 Home 1709 (Fall Creators Update) keeps reinstalling after rollback to 1703

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1703, windows-10-v1709

For reasons unrelated to the question I can't use Windows 10 1709 on a certain PC.  Since none of the urban legends for blocking feature updates work (e.g. setting the ethernet connection to *metered*) I updated to 1709.

In the settings I used the restore option to initiate the rollback to the previous windows version. I even answered the question regarding the reason for doing this.

After the rollback had completed, Windows 1703 immediately started to download and install the 1709 update again.  Is this by design?

I know that there is no (publicly) known way to block a feature update on Windows 10 1703 Home. But a rollback should be permanent IMHO.

Any hints? Except going a brute force way (e.g. deleting the windows update service binaries) to prevent any updates?

I've had limited success blocking the update for some time using a powershell script I've created to set the `IsHidden` member of the 1709 update:

```
$updateSession = New-Object -Com "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$updateSearcher = $updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()    
$available = $updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")
$featureUpdate = $available.Updates | Where-Object { $_.Title -like 'Feature update*'}
$featureUpdate | select Title, IsHidden
$featureUpdate.IsHidden=1
```

However, Windows seems to unhide the 1709 Update after a unspecified period of time.
I've configured the scheduler to call this script on a regular basis.
It is still unknown if this method will block the feature updates permanently.

Comment: Feature updates are required if you are running Windows 10 Home.  You can only defer feature updates if you are running Windows 10 Professional+.  Just because you reverted the upgrade doesn’t chnage the fact they are still required.

Comment: @Ramhound `s/required/forced` if you know what I mean. The question is why MS then even offers a useless rollback option.

Comment: It’s not useless.  The intention is to delay the update until it’s compatible with the update which for more devices happens fairly quickly.  It’s not useless if you can revert and then defer the update.

Comment: Right, if and only if you can defer the update which is obviously not the case on Home editions. Ergo, it is useless there. But discussion like these turn out to get religious very quickly. Fact is that without unofficial hacks the rollback option on Windows 1709 Home is a waste of environmental and psychological resources ;)

Comment: *"I can't use Windows 10 1709 on a certain PC."*  If you don't mind me asking, why?

Comment: @Run5k https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054150/issues-when-windows-10-fall-creators-update-calls-createwindowex-for-s

Comment: I'm having exactly this problem with the new April 2018 update. If I ever meet those who designed this system, they'd better run. FAST.

Comment: Same for me. Had to roll back because April 2018 broke IPv6 tunnels. However, it immediately starts to update again, because I am on the Home version. The rollback option is utterly useless!